# How do I use the facebook api to get another users feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using Impactworks graph handler to get my facebook posts successfully.
http://blog.impact-works.com/2011/07/01/importing-user-info-using-facebook-graph-api-asp-net-part-1/

But how do I get another users posts from their wall? Do they just need to add my app to their facebook?

Answer (score 0):

> Do they just need to add my app to their facebook?

Yes. But, you can get the public posts simply using:

```
/USER_ID/posts

/PAGE_ID/posts
```

, even if the user is not using your app.